# I can't change IP:8000 to mysite.com:8000 using gunicorn

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I have a problem with gunicorn, I can't up my host in my setting.py file like this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://api.colonybit.com',
             'api.colonybit.com',
             'http://colonybit.com:8000',
             '.colonybit.com:8000']
```

and when up to my server with

```
gunicorn --bind colonybit.com:800 colonybitbasics.wsgi:application
```

not working, show me this error

```
 [2018-07-24 11:31:04 -0200] [16840] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('colonybit.com', 800)
```

[2018-07-24 11:31:04 -0200] [16840] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-07-24 11:31:05 -0200] [16840] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('colonybit.com', 800)
[2018-07-24 11:31:05 -0200] [16840] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-07-24 11:31:06 -0200] [16840] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('colonybit.com', 800)
[2018-07-24 11:31:06 -0200] [16840] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-07-24 11:31:07 -0200] [16840] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('colonybit.com', 800)
[2018-07-24 11:31:07 -0200] [16840] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-07-24 11:31:08 -0200] [16840] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('colonybit.com', 800)
[2018-07-24 11:31:08 -0200] [16840] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-07-24 11:31:09 -0200] [16840] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('colonybit.com', 800)

I followed the next link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

in this tutorial, I can't build a file .sock

and the another link: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

not working well

please help me, tell me how to replace IP:8000 with mysite.com:8000

Comment: You use port `800` here, but the accepted one is `8000`...

Comment: thanks, but it was an error to the writting, I user gunicorn --bind colonybit.com:8000 colonybitbasics.wsgi:application

Comment: You shouldn't be binding gunicorn to an external address anyway. Leave it internal and use a reverse proxy like nginx.